# Python Double for loop adding new rows to new Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Python. I want to compare 2 column of elements if they are both identical I want to get their elements from a 3rd column added up them. 
Create a new Numpy array and add all these 3 elements there.
Right now it replaces all the elements and I only get a single vector instead of a long matrix. (the summation works ok)

```
#data is a numpy array 
dataTitle = np.array(["A", "B", "SUM"])
c = 0


for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if((data[i, 0] == data[j, 0]) and (data[i, 1] == data[j, 1])): 
            c += data[j, 3]
    data2 = np.array([[data[j, 0], data[j, 1], c]])
    np.concatenate(dataTitle, data2, axis = 0)
    c = 0
```

Comment: You're concatenating c rather then data2. Change the concatenate line to np.concatenate(dataTitle, data2, axis = 0)

Comment: I have tried like that and it is still not working. But it definitely was an error thx.

Comment: `concatenate` doesn't operate in place.  It's better to build a list of arrays, and join them once at the end.